# Ember.js with multiple jquery ready functions

Tags: jquery, ember.js, kendo-ui

I have a question with regards to jquery ready function used while creating an ember application. I have the following scenario and i don't quite know how to approach it.

I have two pages. In the first one i want to add a [Kendo UI editor](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/editor/index.html) whereby i execute the following code when the DOM is ready:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // create Editor from textarea HTML element with default set of tools
                $("#editor").kendoEditor();
            });
```

In the second page i only want to add a [Kendo UI calendar](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/calendar/index.html) with the following code:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // create Calendar from div HTML element
                $("#calendar").kendoCalendar();
            });
```

I want to execute each code when the appropriate DOM (page) is ready and not all by once within one jquery ready handler.

Could you suggest a way to deal with this issue

Cheers
Pavlos

Comment: I think i found the [solution][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891452/executing-javascript-inside-of-x-handlebars-script

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what you have to do. The code inside didInsertElement will be execute after the view is created and inserted into the dom.